# Where does pam get credential information?

Tags: authentication, pam

I am learning how to write a application program which use pam to do authentication.
I checked the Linux documents and some example codes, now I have a basic understanding about the pam APIs and pam configuration in /etc/pam.d/. But I have a question is where pam get the credential information to do authentication.
E.g.: If the application send the pam request with username "abc" and password "XXXXX". How does pam check the credential information to determine whether authenticate or not ?
If "abc" is not a valid user for my application, but I want to add it as a valid user, how should I do to make pam authenticatin succeed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gotten any further in answering your question? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: No, I didn't get any answers for this question and I don't have progress personally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood your question. 
It depends on the module that does the authentication. For example, if you use `pam_unix.so`, the credentials are checked against `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.
There are several built in modules for authentication and they can use different methods to check your credentials. If you want do do authentication in a custom way (not provided by built in modules), you have to build your module.

Building your module you can decide what to do in every step of the authentication process. For example, you can decide to receive the user credentials, authenticate them against a database (maybe in a remote server) and also add a new user in the way you prefer.

Writing a PAM module is pretty simple, I've written a tutorial about it:

[Writing a Linux PAM module](https://fedetask.com/write-linux-pam-module/)

Hope this will help you. If you have other doubts about the PAM authentication process, I've written also this tutorials:

[Writing a PAM application](https://fedetask.com/writing-a-linux-pam-aware-application/)

[How does PAM work](https://fedetask.com/linux-pam-authentication-made-simple/)